# Finding a $C^1$ surface inside a convex open set (Rudin chapter 10 problem 29)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem is as follows (with $n>1)$:

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a convex open set, and let $F \subseteq \mathbb R^{n-1}$ be it's projection onto the first $n-1$ coordinates. It is clear that $F$ is a convex open set in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

I need to prove that there exists a function $\alpha:F \to \mathbb R$ **of class $\bf{ C^1}$**, such that  it's graph lies in $E$. In other words, for every $x \in F$, $(x,\alpha(x)) \in E$

The book says that the proof is trivial if, for instance, $E$ is a ball, since $\alpha$ can be chosen constant. I have no idea where to start in the general case. I tried using the inverse/implicit function theorems without success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $x \in F$ pick $\bar{x} \in E$ and $\epsilon(x) > 0$ such that the projection of $\bar{x}$ is $x$ and the open ball $V(x) := B_{\epsilon(x)}(\bar{x})$ with center $\bar{x}$ and radius $\epsilon(x)$ is contained in $E$. Now the open balls $U(x) := B_{\epsilon(x)}(x)$ [sic!] cover $F$.

We may find a set of points $x_i$, such that $U(x_i)$ is a locally finite cover of $F$. Let $\phi_i: F \to [0,1]$ be a smooth partition of unity subordinate to this cover.

Since the projection of $V(x_i)$ is $U(x_i)$ and $V(x_i)$ is an open ball, we may choose a constant $c_i \in \mathbb R$ such that $(x,c_i) \in V(x_i)$ for every $x \in U(x_i)$. Using convexity of $E$, we can now conclude that $\alpha(x) := \sum_i \phi_i(x)c_i$ has the desired property.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? The version of the "partitions of unity" in Rudin's book talks about a compact set, which I fail to find here.

Comment: It is just a set of functions such that $\phi_i(x) = 0$ for all $x \in F \setminus U(x_i)$ and $\sum_i \phi_i(x) = 1$ for all $x \in F$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part. Take some point $x \in F$, then $x \in U(x_i)$ for some $x_i$. We know that $(x,c_i) \in E$ but $\alpha(x) \neq c_i$, so why is it true that $(x,\alpha(x)) \in E$?. I can't see how to use the convexity of E, because you took the "convex combination" in the last coordinate only.

Comment: $(x,\sum_i\phi_i(x)c_i) = \sum_i\phi_i(x)(x,c_i)$.